# Doctrine many-to-many with extra field (update and delete specific items)

Tags: symfony, doctrine, many-to-many

Good morning.
I have a problem with update and delete specific items. I searched the entire internet for the answer but didn't find it, nowhere.

**This is what I have**

**1. Action concept:**
Adding a sales invoice to a specific budget to calculate how much is left for settle. Each invoice can be settled up to several project steps.
**Example:**

[image: action concept]

**2. Database relation**

[image: database relation]

**3. Example JSON Request** which is needed to POST and PATCH.

`{"number": "4/2020", "netValue": 4000.00, "budgetsDetails": [{"id": 2, "value": 500.00}, {"id": 3, "value": 3500.00}]}`

**4. Entities**

**SalesInvoice.php**

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="SalesInvoices")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\SalesInvoiceRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class SalesInvoice
{
    use Timestamps;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $number;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2)
     */
    private $netValue;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="SalesInvoiceBudget", mappedBy="salesInvoice", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, fetch="EAGER")
     */
    private $salesInvoiceBudgets;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->salesInvoiceBudgets = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getNumber(): ?string
    {
        return $this->number;
    }

    public function setNumber(string $number): self
    {
        $this->number = $number;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNetValue(): ?string
    {
        return $this->netValue;
    }

    public function setNetValue(string $netValue): self
    {
        $this->netValue = $netValue;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|SalesInvoiceBudget[]
     */
    public function getSalesInvoiceBudgets(): Collection
    {
        return $this->salesInvoiceBudgets;
    }

    public function addSalesInvoiceBudget(SalesInvoiceBudget $salesInvoiceBudget): self
    {
        if (!$this->salesInvoiceBudgets->contains($salesInvoiceBudget)) {
            $this->salesInvoiceBudgets[] = $salesInvoiceBudget;
            $salesInvoiceBudget->setSalesInvoice($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeSalesInvoiceBudget(SalesInvoiceBudget $salesInvoiceBudget): self
    {
        if ($this->salesInvoiceBudgets->contains($salesInvoiceBudget)) {
            $this->salesInvoiceBudgets->removeElement($salesInvoiceBudget);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($salesInvoiceBudget->getSalesInvoice() === $this) {
                $salesInvoiceBudget->setSalesInvoice(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**SalesInvoiceBudget.php**

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="SalesInvoices_ProjectBudgets")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\SalesInvoiceBudgetRepository")
 */
class SalesInvoiceBudget
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SalesInvoice", inversedBy="salesInvoiceBudgets", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $salesInvoice;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ProjectBudget", inversedBy="salesInvoiceBudgets", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $budget;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2)
     */
    private $value;


    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getValue(): ?string
    {
        return $this->value;
    }

    public function setValue(string $value): self
    {
        $this->value = $value;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSalesInvoice(): ?SalesInvoice
    {
        return $this->salesInvoice;
    }

    public function setSalesInvoice(?SalesInvoice $salesInvoice): self
    {
        $this->salesInvoice = $salesInvoice;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getBudget(): ?ProjectBudget
    {
        return $this->budget;
    }

    public function setBudget(?ProjectBudget $budget): self
    {
        $this->budget = $budget;

        return $this;
    }
}
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="SalesInvoices_ProjectBudgets")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\SalesInvoiceBudgetRepository")
 */
class SalesInvoiceBudget
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SalesInvoice", inversedBy="salesInvoiceBudgets", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $salesInvoice;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ProjectBudget", inversedBy="salesInvoiceBudgets", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $budget;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2)
     */
    private $value;


    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getValue(): ?string
    {
        return $this->value;
    }

    public function setValue(string $value): self
    {
        $this->value = $value;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSalesInvoice(): ?SalesInvoice
    {
        return $this->salesInvoice;
    }

    public function setSalesInvoice(?SalesInvoice $salesInvoice): self
    {
        $this->salesInvoice = $salesInvoice;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getBudget(): ?ProjectBudget
    {
        return $this->budget;
    }

    public function setBudget(?ProjectBudget $budget): self
    {
        $this->budget = $budget;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**ProjectBudget.php**

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="ProjectBudgets")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ProjectBudgetRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class ProjectBudget
{
    use Timestamps;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2, nullable=true)
     */
    private $budgetAmount;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="SalesInvoiceBudget", mappedBy="budget", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
     */
    private $salesInvoiceBudgets;
    

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->salesInvoiceBudgets = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getBudgetAmount(): ?string
    {
        return $this->budgetAmount;
    }

    public function setBudgetAmount(?string $budgetAmount): self
    {
        $this->budgetAmount = $budgetAmount;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|SalesInvoiceBudget[]
     */
    public function getSalesInvoiceBudgets(): Collection
    {
        return $this->salesInvoiceBudgets;
    }

    public function addSalesInvoiceBudget(SalesInvoiceBudget $salesInvoiceBudget): self
    {
        if (!$this->salesInvoiceBudgets->contains($salesInvoiceBudget)) {
            $this->salesInvoiceBudgets[] = $salesInvoiceBudget;
            $salesInvoiceBudget->setBudget($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeSalesInvoiceBudget(SalesInvoiceBudget $salesInvoiceBudget): self
    {
        if ($this->salesInvoiceBudgets->contains($salesInvoiceBudget)) {
            $this->salesInvoiceBudgets->removeElement($salesInvoiceBudget);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($salesInvoiceBudget->getBudget() === $this) {
                $salesInvoiceBudget->setBudget(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**5. Part of controller**

```
    /**
     * @Rest\RequestParam(name="number")
     * @Rest\RequestParam(name="netValue")
     * @Rest\RequestParam(name="budgetsDetails", nullable=true)
     * @param ParamFetcher $paramFetcher
     * @return View
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function postSinvoiceAction(ParamFetcher $paramFetcher)
    {
        $number = $paramFetcher->get('number');
        $netValue = $paramFetcher->get('netValue');
        $budgetsDetails = $paramFetcher->get('budgetsDetails');

        if($number === null) {
            return $this->view(null, Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        $contractor = $this->contractorRepository->findOneBy(array("id" => $contractorId));

        $invoice = new SalesInvoice();
        $invoice->setNumber($number);
        $invoice->setNetValue($netValue);

        if ($budgetsDetails && sizeof($budgetsDetails) > 0) {
            foreach ($budgetsDetails as $budgetDetails) {
                $budget = $this->projectBudgetRepository->findOneBy(array('id' => $budgetDetails['id']));

                if ($budget === null) {
                    return $this->view("There is no budget like this.");
                }

                $relation = new SalesInvoiceBudget();
                $relation->setBudget($budget);
                $relation->setValue($budgetDetails['value']);
                $invoice->addSalesInvoiceBudget($relation);
            }
        }

        $this->entityManager->persist($invoice);
        $this->entityManager->flush();

        return $this->view("Added.", Response::HTTP_CREATED);
    }
}
```

Adding a new invoice with the assignment of the amount to the project stage using the above JSON works, but I have no idea how to edit and delete the assigned budget when someone makes a mistake when entering the amount to be settled or settles the wrong stage of the project.

Comment: Are you asking how to query for a particular SalesInvoiceBudget?

Comment: When someone sends a modified JSON like this:
```{"number": "4/2020", "netValue": 4000.00, "budgetsDetails": [{"id": 2, "value": 500.00}, {"id": 1, "value": 800.00}]}```
I would like to remove unused, add new and edit existing ones. Generally do operations on the "sales_invoices_project_budgets" table.

Comment: There is no builtin solution that I am aware of.  It will take a few steps and depend in part on your overall design.  Start by adding a SalesInvoiceBudgetRepository::findBySalesInvoiceNumber($number); method.  That will give you a list of all the current budget details for a given invoice.  After that it is a question of comparing the list against data and figuring out what needs to be changed.  Just take it one step at a time.  Setting up a functional test for this sort of thing can be a big help.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to reach my goal but I think it looks terrible. It works, but it probably isn't coded as it should...

```
/**
     * @Rest\RequestParam(name="number")
     * @Rest\RequestParam(name="netValue")
     * @Rest\RequestParam(name="budgetsDetails", nullable=true)
     * @param ParamFetcher $paramFetcher
     * @param SalesInvoice $invoice
     * @return View
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function patchSinvoiceAction(ParamFetcher $paramFetcher, SalesInvoice $invoice)
    {
        $number = $paramFetcher->get('number');
        $netValue = $paramFetcher->get('netValue');
        $budgetsDetails = $paramFetcher->get('budgetsDetails');

        if($number === null) {
            return $this->view(null, Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        }        

        $invoice->setNumber($number);
        $invoice->setNetValue($netValue);

        if ($budgetsDetails && sizeof($budgetsDetails) > 0) {
            foreach ($budgetsDetails as $item) {
               // Iterating the record found in the request.
               if ($relation = $this->salesInvoiceBudgetRepository->findOneBy(array('budget' => $item['id'], 'salesInvoice' => $invoice->getId()))) {
                   // An existing record in the database that matches the request was found. Edit.
                   $relation->setValue($item['value']);
               } else {
                   // There is no matching database record for the request. Adding a record.
                   $budget = $this->projectBudgetRepository->findOneBy(array('id' => $item['id']));
                   $relation = new SalesInvoiceBudget();
                   $relation->setBudget($budget);
                   $relation->setValue($item['value']);
                   $invoice->addSalesInvoiceBudget($relation);
               }
            }
            // Clearing the database of records that are not in the request. Since they are not there, they must be removed.
            $relations = $invoice->getSalesInvoiceBudgets();
            foreach ($relations as $relation) {
                if (!in_array($relation->getBudget()->getId(), array_column($budgetsDetails, 'id'))) {
                    // A record was found in the database that is not in the request. Delete a record.
                    $relation->getSalesInvoice()->removeSalesInvoiceBudget($relation);
                }
            }
        }

        $this->entityManager->persist($invoice);
        $this->entityManager->flush();

        return $this->view("Added.", Response::HTTP_CREATED);
    }
```

Comment: This sort of code is almost always a bit messy no matter how you approach it.  This part, $invoice->setNumber($number); looks suspicious.  I would think the $invoice passed would have already been queried by $number.  Updating it seems wrong somehow.  But if it does what you need then okay.

Comment: I don't undestand this sentence a bit : "I would think the $invoice passed would have already been queried by $number."

Comment: How is $invoice being instantiated?  I assume it is being loaded from the database.  Is it being loaded by id or number?

Comment: In API path I type id of invoice but in controller method parameter is invoice object. If I want to update invoice number I need to set it,.

Comment: Always be careful passing around ids.  Remember that it's trivial for a user to change them.  And it seems like having invoice numbers such as '4/2020' is not the sort of thing you want users to be able to casually modify.  Getting back to your original question:  one reason that the code is so messy is that you are trying to do quite a few things with one request.  Updating invoice, for example, could have it's very own action.

Comment: I thought that updating a record is updating all its elements. I think I know what you mean about creating a few actions but I'm not sure if it would make sense in this case.